# R error in package "glmnet": error backage foreach

Tags: r, rstudio

I have R version 3.4.3. I'm working on a school project with `glmnet`.
 
I've tried to install the package and I didn't get any error code, but when I ask for with `library(glmnet)` I get these errors.
I have tried to remove it, installing it back, install `foreach` alone: the same problem!!

```
install.packages("glmnet", dependencies=TRUE)

Installing package into �C:/Users/freel_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.4�
(as �lib� is unspecified)
also installing the dependency �foreach�

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/foreach_1.4.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 388581 bytes (379 KB)
downloaded 379 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/glmnet_2.0-13.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1769167 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB

package ‘foreach’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘glmnet’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\freel_000\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpy4iKye\downloaded_packages`
```

Comment: Please, share the error messages given by `library(glmnet)`

Comment: "loading foreach couldn't found"

Comment: Try to install `iterators` and `codetools` libraries